# Single Factory for multiple Controllers?

Tags: zend-framework2

My question in short: Can I use a single Factory for multiple Controllers?

More details:

I have some global non-module specific settings in */config/autoload/global.php* which look like this:

```
return array(
    'settings' => array(
        'setting_a' => 'foo',
        'setting_b' => 'bar'
    ),

    // More ZF default configuration ...
);
```

Now I want to make these settings accessable in every controller without having to call `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('config')` all the time.

So my idea was to introduce a class attribute `$settings` in my `AbstractController` which get’s injected with the configuration array. I tried to fetch the config directly in the constructor of `AbstractController`. However `getServiceLocator()` doesn’t seem ready at the time and returns NULL.

I could build Controller Factories for every controller and inject the settings like this:

```
class ControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        return new \MyModule\Controller\MyController($config['settings']);
    }
}
```

But it would be the same over and over again. So my question is: Can I use a single Factory for multiple controllers?

In my *module.config.php* I could specify a single factory class for multiple controllers:

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyModule\Controller\MyControllerA' => 'MyModule\Factory\ControllerFactory',
            'MyModule\Controller\MyControllerB' => 'MyModule\Factory\ControllerFactory',
            'MyModule\Controller\MyControllerC' => 'MyModule\Factory\ControllerFactory',
        )
    ),
);
```

But in the factory I need to return the actual Controller object by hand (see example above) which of course only works with one Factory per Controller.

Hope, I made my problem clear.

**UPDATE 2013-03-24:**

Although I first followed the suggested solution by creating an initializer, I never really liked using it just for the injection of the configuration.

So I kept digging around and ended up creating a Controller plugin to receive the settings.

The code for the plugin looks like this:

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class Settings extends AbstractPlugin
{
    protected $settings;

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $config = $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');

        if (isset($config['settings']) && is_array($config['settings'])) {
            $this->settings = $config['settings'];
        }

        return $this->settings;
    }
}
```

After adding the plugin in *module.config.php* with

```
'controller_plugins' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'settings' => 'My\Controller\Plugin\Settings',
    )
),
```

I can easily access my settings within a controller by simply calling `$this->settings()`. Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try attaching an initializer, then as the controller is created the instance is checked against known initializers. If the instance matches a given interface or abstract class, then you can apply some common logic.

I've not tested this approach with controllers but given that the ControllerLoader is a type of ServiceManager/ServiceLocator it should in theory work.

```
'controllers' => array (
    'initializers' => array(
        'MyApplication\Controller\Initializer'
    )
),
```

Then the Initalizer would look something like:

```
class Initializer implements InitializerInterface
{
    public function initialize($instance, ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        if (!$instance instanceof MyControllerInterface)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Do something for this instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. The initializer itself works like you described, however once I add it to the 'controllers' array, the controller mappings somehow get lost and I get an error saying *"The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class."* It seems that both 'invokables' and 'initializers' within 'controllers' bite each other. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would rewind back to just invokables then apply the initializer – then debug if the initializer is getting an instance. The error message thrown could be for a number of reasons, make sure all use definitions are correct and there are no errors. To dig deeper I would also take a look at \Zend\Mvc\Service\ControllerLoaderFactory.php and follow it through to \Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager.php – I hope that helps.

Comment: Found the cause: It's the `$serviceLocator->get('Config')` call in Initializer::initialize() which throws a *service not found exception*. So it seems the config is not ready at initialization phase. And I still cannot get my settings into the controller :-( Will try a workaround now.

Comment: First try var_dump on $serviceLocator (with xdebug enabled) should give you a hint of what you can pull at that point. Also try $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Config') as it maybe the plugin ServiceManager not the main one.

Comment: DrBeza, you’re the best! `$serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('Config')` indeed fixed the problem! Finally I’ve got my settings in all of my controllers! Thank you for your very helpful support!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you did a future update "UPDATE 2013-03-24" ;)

Why don't you just use controllers like you suggested but put the code you want in all controllers into an abstract factory from which you then inherit, for example:

```
abstract class AbstractControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    protected function initialise(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $controller) {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        $controller->setConfig($config);
    }
}

class ControllerFactory extends AbstractControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $controller = new \MyModule\Controller\MyController();
        $this->initialise($serviceLocator, $controller);
        return $controller;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or even cleaner: add your controllers as invokables to the config, then do something like this which turns your controllers into one-liners:

```
abstract class AbstractControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    protected $controllerKey;

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $config     = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        $controller = $serviceLocator->get($this->controllerKey);
        $controller->setConfig($config);
        return $controller;
    }
}

class ControllerFactory extends AbstractControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    protected $controllerKey = 'mymodule_controller_mycontroller';
}
```